# Bulding a labelling dataset and modelling categorical features

Tags: categorical-data, multilabel, labeling, train-test-split

Summary: How do I ensure that sample I create for labelling is representative enough and would be appropriate for modelling, given I cannot include all feature combinations in it.

I have a tabular dataset of about 8000 samples (unique IDs) in the following format

| ID | Feature 1 | Feature 2 | ... | Feature 10 | Target |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | Low | Medium | ... | High | Medium |

All my features are categorical and can take one of the three values Low, Medium, and High. My target is also categorical and can take the same values and is imbalanced with relatively few Highs, a significant number of Mediums, and even more Lows.

No feature selection could be performed, since the features are mandated by regulation (dumb but it is what it is).

I need to build a supervised model that predicts the target, given the features.

I do not have a "ground truth" - the current "target" I am talking about is a product of another model that used to be based on expert judgement and has been shown to be relatively accurate historically, but as you might see it should not be used for a variety of reasons (bias, circular logic, etc). Therefore, a labelling exercise would be carried out, where analysts are given a data sample and need to label it. I envision the labelling to be on a 5 or 7 point scale that is then remapped to the 3 levels - Low, Medium, High in order to keep some granularity. Here comes my first question - in the population there are about 1500 unique combinations of the 10 features. However, we can give analysts a maximum of 500 samples to label. 1) How do best to sample s.t. the sample we give analysts to label is representative of the population and so that the model can learn to generalize on unseen data.

Another important point is "data leakeage"- when splitting train and test split it is often the case (39% overlap with 100 iterations bootstrapping) that a particular combination of features appears in both train and test sets. In principle, this would be data leakeage, but in this case I do not think this is the case, since it is different IDs. In addition, it is perfectly possible that a new unseen sample comes and has the same feature combination as a sample in the train set. Then the model would (correctly in my eyes) predict the new sample and I do not believe this would be cheating. 2) Could you please provide an opinion on this and on an idea of how you would split the data? Would you have a feature combination in train and test even when it is two different IDs?

Lastly, I would be happy if you share any practical advice on how to model the dataset. 3) Do you see particular issues, given all the features and the target are ordinal and categorical?

I hope the questions are concrete enough and would be happy if people could comment on 1), 2), and 3).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @utobi Thank you
I tried editing in 1 specific question under Summary:
Let me know if that helps